# Creating ant task to build ArcGIS Viewer for Flex?

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer

Has anybody created ant task to build ArcGIS for Flex Viewer?

I want to put ArcGIS Flex Viewer into our Continuous Integration system (Hudson).

So far it's a very difficult task to do.

Comment: I seen that you use maven to build our Flex Viewers. it is possible to provide the pom.xml files?
I tried to use ant but is to be a difficult task
Thanks

Comment: This appears to be a new question, consider adding it as such.

Answer (score 1):

We are using maven to build our Flex Viewers.
If you are interested, I can provide you the pom.xml files.